# Discount on certain grand total of a specific category

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

What is the best way to do this discount on a category level? That category is a specific brand which 93 products there all apply so i don't want to make a ton of actions and conditions. Is this possible?

- 11.88 total give 3.96 discount
- 20.88 total give 6.96 discount
- 29.97 total give 9.99 discount

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to set this up in a scaleable way in default Magento CE. The price could be done with a percentage but grouping the products per category would be hard

Answer (score 1):

You could set it up as tiered pricing but it wouldn't show as a discount.

93 products could be done quite quickly with export/import and modifing the .csv file

You could show the discount in the description